Go/Gin/sqlc REST API endpoint that can update data to empty string
I am trying to understand marshalling of JSON in Go. I am a little bit confused because of Go's string nil value being "", which has a different semantic than a NULL.
While my code currently works fine, I'm not happy with how I'm dealing with it and would love some advice to write it cleaner.
I have a db table called authors with name and bio column.
I want to build a REST API that can update it's value.
I want to only update the value if key is present in the json request.
{"name": "new name"} // only update "name"
{"name": "new name", "bio": ""} // update "name" and "bio"

This is my current code:
func (s *Server) UpdateAuthor(c *gin.Context) {
    authorId := c.Param("id")
    id, err := strconv.ParseInt(authorId, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
            "error": err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }

    author, err := s.Query.GetAuthor(c, id)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "error": err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }

    var input UpdateAuthorInput
    if err := c.BindJSON(&input); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
            "error": err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }

    updatedAuthor := input.data(author)
    author, err = s.Query.UpdateAuthor(c, updatedAuthor)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "error": err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, author)
}

type UpdateAuthorInput struct {
    Name *string `json:"name"`
    Bio  *string `json:"bio"`
}

func (a UpdateAuthorInput) data(current data.Author) data.UpdateAuthorParams {
    params := data.UpdateAuthorParams{
        ID:   current.ID,
        Name: current.Name,
        Bio:  current.Bio,
    }

    if a.Name != nil {
        params.Name = *a.Name
    }

    if a.Bio != nil {
        params.Bio = sql.NullString{String: *a.Bio, Valid: true}
    }

    return params
}


sqlc generated type:
type UpdateAuthorParams struct {
    Name string         `json:"name"`
    Bio  sql.NullString `json:"bio"`
    ID   int64          `json:"id"`
}

func (q *Queries) UpdateAuthor(ctx context.Context, arg UpdateAuthorParams) (Author, error) {
    row := q.db.QueryRowContext(ctx, updateAuthor, arg.Name, arg.Bio, arg.ID)
    var i Author
    err := row.Scan(&i.ID, &i.Name, &i.Bio)
    return i, err
}

Everything works but I'm not happy with it because I have to check the property one by one.
I was wondering if there is a more cleaner and less error prone way to convert UpdateAuthorInput -> data.UpdateAuthorParams ?

I think validator package will help you. Or gin validator. Do these help you?

We can use some validator packages for validating requests. Some Web frameworks like gin have their own validators.
See:

gin model binding and validation
validator package

You can add some rules on struct tags. See following code in your case:
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type UpdateAuthorParams struct {
    Name string `json:"name" binding:"required"`
    Bio  string `json:"bio" binding:"required"`
    ID   int64  `json:"id" binding:"required"`
}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.POST("/path", func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        var uap UpdateAuthorParams
        if err := ctx.ShouldBindJSON(&uap); err != nil {
            ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"message": err.Error()})
            return
        }
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"message": "everythings is ok!"})
    })

    r.Run(":8000")
}

Let examine our code after launching program:
$ curl -w'\n' -XPOST localhost:8000/path -d '{"name":"ali", "bio":"im a developer", "id":1}'
{"message":"everythings is ok!"}
$ curl -w'\n' -XPOST localhost:8000/path -d '{"name":"ali", "bio":"im a developer", "id":"1"}'
{"message":"json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field UpdateAuthorParams.id of type int64"}
$ curl -w'\n' -XPOST localhost:8000/path -d '{"name":"ali", "id":1}'
{"message":"Key: 'UpdateAuthorParams.Bio' Error:Field validation for 'Bio' failed on the 'required' tag"}
$ curl -w'\n' -XPOST localhost:8000/path -d ''
{"message":"EOF"}
$ 

Even you can combine go-playground/validator and gin validator, and generate custom struct-level validators. See this page.

name and bio is not required on updating. {"name":"ali", "id":1} should not fail. it means the user only wants to update the name column and keep the bio column untouched.
